# How do I add the contents of an array into a spreadsheet using Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, axlsx

I am scraping a webpage at http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ie/en/ho/WF06b/321957-321957-3329742-89318-89318-5186820-5231694.html?dnr=1

First I create my array of desired keywords (clues), I then perform an Xpath query feeding the results into CSV. Everything works smoothly but the spreadsheet needs better formatting so end users can copy and paste

Is there a way I can achieve my desired look using either CSV or Axslx

My code is below:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'   
require 'open-uri'
require 'CSV'
require 'axlsx'

#Set encoding options to remove nasty Trademark symbols
  encoding_options = {
    :invalid           => :replace,  # Replace invalid byte sequences
    :undef             => :replace,  # Replace anything not defined in ASCII
    :replace           => '',        # Use a blank for those replacements
    :universal_newline => true       # Always break lines with \n
  }

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ie/en/ho/WF06b/321957-321957-3329742-89318-89318-5186820-5231694.html?dnr=1"))
#For each break create a ;
doc.css('br').each{ |br| br.replace ';' }

clues = Array.new
clues << 'Operating system'
clues << 'Processors'
clues << 'Chipset'
clues << 'Memory type'
clues << 'Hard drive'
clues << 'Graphics'
clues << 'Ports'
clues << 'Webcam'
clues << 'Pointing device'
clues << 'Keyboard'
clues << 'Network interface'
clues << 'Chipset'
clues << 'Wireless'
clues << 'Power supply type'
clues << 'Energy efficiency'
clues << 'Weight'
clues << 'Minimum dimensions (W x D x H)'
clues << 'Warranty'
clues << 'Software included'
clues << 'Product color'

CSV.open("output.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  #1. Output the Clues header
  #2. Scrape the output/force encoding to remove special characters
    csv << clues
    csv << clues.map{|clue| doc.at("//td[text()='#{clue}']/following-sibling::td").text.strip.encode Encoding.find('ASCII'), encoding_options}
  #end loop
end
```

My code can add the entire array to one line but how do I say foreach item in the array add it to a newline? I tried \n but it didn't work.

**The Output I get**

[image: The output I get]

**My Desired output**

[image: My desired output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is randym, the author of axlsx. I think you want to be doing this:

```
clues = Array.new
clues << 'Operating system'
clues << 'Processors'
clues << 'Chipset'
clues << 'Memory type'

Axlsx::Package.new do |p|
  p.workbook do |wb|
    wb.add_worksheet do |sheet|
      clues.each { |clue| sheet.add_row [clue] }
    end
  end
  p.serialize 'My_Spreadsheet.xlsx'
end
```

As to your second question:

```
selector = "//td[text()='%s']/following-sibling::td"
data = clues.map do |clue| 
         xpath = selector % clue
         [clue, doc.at(xpath).text.strip]
       end
```

Then use

```
data.each { |datum| sheet.add_row datum }
```

when you build the worksheet

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'   
require 'open-uri'
require 'axlsx'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ie/en/ho/WF06b/321957-321957-3329742-89318-89318-5186820-5231694.html?dnr=1"))
#For each break create a ;
doc.css('br').each{ |br| br.replace ';' }

clues = Array.new
clues << 'Operating system'
clues << 'Processors'
clues << 'Chipset'
clues << 'Memory type'
clues << 'Hard drive'
clues << 'Graphics'
clues << 'Ports'
clues << 'Webcam'
clues << 'Pointing device'
clues << 'Keyboard'
clues << 'Network interface'
clues << 'Chipset'
clues << 'Wireless'
clues << 'Power supply type'
clues << 'Energy efficiency'
clues << 'Weight'
clues << 'Minimum dimensions (W x D x H)'
clues << 'Warranty'
clues << 'Software included'
clues << 'Product color'

selector = "//td[text()='%s']/following-sibling::td"
data = clues.map do |clue| 
         xpath = selector % clue
         [clue, doc.at(xpath).text.strip]
       end

Axlsx::Package.new do |p|
  p.workbook.add_worksheet do |sheet|
    data.each { |datum| sheet.add_row datum }
  end
  p.serialize 'output.xlsx'
end
```

Screen shots for your pleasure.
[image]

Comment: Hi randym thanks for the reply, I am not a programmer so bear with me. I have edited my question so maybe you can see what I need to do.

Comment: Ninja2k - you *are* a programmer! you are solving your problems using code. Ive updated my answer with a full example from your source code that will generate the sheet you are looking for.

Comment: Brilliant!! thank you for that it work like a charm, this was the first ruby program I ever made! I am a Network Engineer by trade but needed to get some specs for a bunch of computers without the carpal tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

Use each to iterate over the array:

```
clues.each do |clue|
  sheet.add_row [clue]
end
```

Comment: How can I do this with something more complicated such as an Xpath query. My full code is at https://gist.github.com/3205801

Comment: One question per ummm question... ;) Also you might want to clarify what you want - just looking at your code, I don't know what's not working.

Comment: sorry tried to make it simple in the question, but made it too simple ;( updated it to include pictures of what I need and a little more info

Comment: It's cool, looks like the author of the gem is here to help now, so I'm sure you couldn't be in better hands. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
CSV.open("output.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  clues.each do |clue|
    value = doc.at("//td[text()='#{clue}']/following-sibling::td").text.strip.encode Encoding.find('ASCII'), encoding_options
    cvs << [clue, value]
  end
end
```